# How to get the index of the main item on screen from 2 nested PageViews?

Tags: flutter, dart, pageviews, flutter-pageview

I have nested **PageView**s, the outer one is *vertical* (can scroll up and down) and the inner pageview is *horisontal* (can go left and right) - In each row of the vertical scrol view I have horizontal pageview.

Based on the code here, I get the correct index for outer pageview which I call it `rowIndx` but wrong one for inner pageview. For example when I am on `rowIndx = 0` and `columnIndx = 2` I see correct numbers printed in the console, when I scroll down, I get `rowIndx = 1` and `columnIndx = 2` instead of `rowIndx = 1` and `columnIndx = 0`.

The index of columns will update only if you scroll right or left at least once in each row.
How can I get correct index immediately on any card?

You can get index printed in console by tapping on each card. The text on each card shows the correct number for `columnIndx` to make it easy to compare with what is printed in the console.

Thanks for your help in advance.

````
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int rowIndx = 0;
  int columnIndx = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            rowIndx = index;
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return PageView.builder(
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  columnIndx = index;
                },
                controller:
                    PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
                itemCount: sampleCard.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(
                          'column : $columnIndx   in horizontal scroll > left and right');
                      print(
                          'row : $rowIndx   in vertical scroll > up and down');
                    },
                    child: sampleCard[ind],
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}
List sampleCard = [
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Center(
        child: Text(
      'column 0',
    )),
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    child: Center(
        child: Text(
      'column 1',
    )),
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    child: Center(
        child: Text(
      'column 2',
    )),
  ),
];```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can seperate the return widget in inner pageview into a stateless widget and get the column and row from that widget as following:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int rowIndx = 0;
  int columnIndx = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            rowIndx = index;
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return PageView.builder(
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  columnIndx = index;
                },
                controller:
                    PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
                itemCount: sampleCard.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
                  return _Cards(
                    column: ind,
                    row: index,
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}

class _Cards extends StatelessWidget {
  final int column;
  final int row;

  const _Cards({Key? key, required this.column, required this.row})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('column : $column   in horizontal scroll > left and right');
        print('row : $row   in vertical scroll > up and down');
      },
      child: sampleCard[column],
    );
  }
}
```